# Как достать id последней записи mysqli?

Tags: ооп, mysqli, php

Доброго времени! такой вопрос: 
Есть метод который записывает меседж в базу, берет последний id записи, и сразу перезаписывает его.

```
function OmenaInsertDb($msg){
                      if($_SESSION['uid']==""){
                        $sql = "INSERT INTO msg (msg) VALUES ('$msg')";
                        $result = $this->_db->query($sql);  
                        $result->insert_id;
                        $sql = "UPDATE msg SET uid='$uid' WHERE id=='$uid'";
                        $result = $this->_db->query($sql);
                      }
```

То есть есть поля в базе id | msg | uid

Изначально поле uid пустое мне нужно чтобы оно перезаписывалось автоинкрементарным id если не открыта сессия. Не спрашивайте зачем эта глупость)) просто как обратиться к последней добавленой строке и перезаписать её взяв id-шник?

Comment: а что такое по вашему $uid ? может надо присвоить его в предыдущей строке ? и в sql сравнение не `==` а `=`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Курсор" после добавления записи в таблицу ставится на последню добавленную запись.

Comment: И что к чему? ошибка в моем написании какая?

Comment: id=='$uid' должно быть id='$uid', это не PHP :)

Comment: Благодарю! в шары долбимся)